# WhatsApp desktop in Opera not playing videos or offering download

Tags: video, codecs

Using Ubuntu 21.04, GNOME 3.38.5 I am new to Linux.
I have the WhatsApp desktop messenger feature enabled in Opera web browser. (I used this arrangement under MS Win10 with no problem.) The videos will not play ("The video can't be payed") and the download video option is greyed-out.
I have followed the instructions here (the answers seem old- 2015 - but they are the same on linuxhint.com) to download and install codecs
: $ sudo apt update
: $ sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
Still no joy :-(

Comment: have you tried this with the Whatsdesk snap downloadable from the ubuntu software center?

Comment: That works!
Does that make it an Opera issue rather than a Ubuntu codec one?

Comment: Great. More likely a WhatsApp issue than Opera. I'll post that as an answer then if you'd care to accept it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Whatsdesk App downloadable from the ubuntu software center works well with ubuntu and usually overcomes the many issues with the substantive WhatsApp utility which many have reported as being problematical.

[image]